Linearity of differential forms
I put my hands on "Linear Algebra" by Serge Lang, second edition, and I noticed that it contains some sections that were later removed in the following third one. In one of the removed parts from that edition there was a section about tensor products and differential forms. Here, assuming that $\{e^1,e^2,e^3\}$ is a basis of $V$ and $\{dx,dy,dz\}$ is a basis of $V^*$, it is stated [XIII, §3, p.314]:

[...] By a differential form on $\mathbb R^3$ of degree $2$, one means a map (not necessarily linear!)
$$\omega: \mathbb R^3\rightarrow V^*\land V^*$$
form $\mathbb R^3$ into the alternating product of the dual space with itself. [...]

Now, I am a bit confused as I thought differential forms were linear, am I wrong? Can you make one/some examples?

They are multilinear

The point is that $2$-forms are a module over the ring of smooth functions generated by $dx\wedge dy$, $dz\wedge dx$, and $dy\wedge dz$.

Each $V^\ast \wedge V^\ast$ is linear (or multilinear). But what is possibly nonlinear is the function from $\mathbb R^3$ into $V^\ast \wedge V^\ast$. In my opinion, Serge Lang, while technically still correct, should have been more careful with the language here.

The mapping $\omega:X=\Bbb{R}^3\to V^*\wedge V^*$ is not required to be linear, but for each point $x\in X$ the element $\omega_x$ belongs to $V^*\wedge V^*$; this space is canonically isomorphic to $(V\wedge V)^*$ and so $\omega_x$ can be thought of as a linear map $V\wedge V\to\Bbb{R}$, or equivalently as a bilinear alternating map $V\times V\to\Bbb{R}$. You’re confusing yourself because you’re not being precise about what object the linearity is referring to (and it doesn’t help that Lang used the whole of $\Bbb{R}^3$ as the domain, which is easy to misinterpret as a vector space, when in fact you’re only supposed to think of it as a smooth manifold here). So, to be clear:

$\omega$ is not required to be linear (and in most cases the domain is not even going to be a vector space so it won’t make sense to speak of linearity of $\omega$)
$\omega_x$ is (or can be identified with) a linear map $V\wedge V\to\Bbb{R}$ (or equivalently a bilinear alternating map $V\times V\to\Bbb{R}$).

See Connection between the linear algebra and calculus explanation of linearity of the derivative operator for a somewhat related question where OP is confused because of not being careful in identifying which object “linearity” refers to.

Thank you for your clear and kind answer, it conceptually helped a lot.

So do you also mean that when people answered above, they only meant that any $\omega_x \in V^\land V^$ is a multilinear form, nothing to do with properties of $\omega \in ^{\mathbb R^3}( V^\land V^)$ (or $( V^\land V^)^{\mathbb R^3}$), which as you said, could also only be a smooth manifold without vector space structure, right?

Like I said in my answer, $\omega_x$ is the multilinear map. But this has nothing to do with $\omega$ as a whole.

Also, be careful: for any set $X$, the set $(V^\wedge V^)^{X}$ does form a vector space under pointwise addition and scalar multiplication. But this is very different from saying that a specific element $\omega\in (V^\wedge V^)^{X}$ is a linear map, and in fact this statement wouldn’t even make sense in general if $X$ itself is not a vector space.

@peek-a-boo Okay, you fully answered all my doubts, thank you again. I also didn't think about what you said in your last comment, but it still was an interesting point.
